# Dynamics 2013 How can I set the modified on value for activities that I am importing?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am attempting to import a large database into Dynamics 2013, which has a lot of activities against Accounts and Contacts. When I import the Phone Calls/Emails etc. they all appear in the Activity feed labeled as today. I have Over-ridden the Created on date, but the feed is ordered by the modified on column.

If this was for on premises I'd just go into the database and run an SQL query, but since this is destined for Online that's not an option, I have tried creating a plugin but that seems to ignore/over-ride the change.

Has anyone got any inspired ways of over-riding the modified on date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the value of `ModifiedOn` in a Online organization. There is no CRM SDK call that will allow the setting of the `ModifiedOn` date of a record. Therefore without SQL access, as you state in your question, this value cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much the conclusion that I had come to, was just hoping that I was wrong.

Comment: This is only true for Activities and Cases.  Most (if not all) other entities you can override the created/modified attributes.

Comment: @PaulWay - That is incorrect, you can override the CreatedOn by using the `overriddencreatedon` field. There is no override field for `CreatedBy`, `ModifiedBy`, or `ModifiedOn`. If you look at the SDK you'll see all these fields are not valid for Create or Update (on any entity.)

Comment: @Nicknow these do not have an override field, but the values can be changed (without using SQL).

Comment: @PaulWay - No they cannot. If you are able to you have found a bug in Dynamics CRM. Look at the SDK for any entity - it specifies those fields are not valid for Create or Update. You can control the `ModifiedBy` and `CreatedBy` by using impersonation but that is not the same as setting the value, and has serious limitations. You cannot control the `ModifiedBy` or `ModifiedOn` fields - those will be set by the Dynamics CRM platform as current user and time. You could try a pre-create plugin but there is no guarantee b/c it is outside the SDK supported capabilities.

Comment: @Nicknow I agree, it could be considered a bug.  I was able to get Activities and Cases also working.  Looks like all dates are editable, but I'm sure it's unsupported.

Comment: I hate to dig up an old thread, but @PaulWay do you remember how you get Activities working?  I've got a simple pre-create plugin that works fine for Notes but Activities (Phone Call) won't budge, even though the plugin says it's successfully updating ModifiedOn and ModifiedBy.

Answer (score 1):

you can update modified on through a pre-update plugin in CRM online or on-prem. This is the only *supported* solution.

You may also modify SQL directly.

http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/crm-2011-2013-modify-createdon-createdby-modifiedon-modifiedby-using-SDK-CSharp.html